# should I stain the bottom of exterior steps?

Tags: exterior, sealer, steps

When staining exterior steps should I also stain the bottom of the steps? I ask because I think it might better to leave the bottom unstained to let any moisture in the wood evaporate. There would be no stagnant water on the bottom surface of the steps to guard against, in any case.

Answer (score 5):

You should always seal (when you say stain I'm guessing you mean seal) all 4 sides and both ends of a board (if possible) so it takes in moisture/humidity evenly. Otherwise it can lead to cupping, warping, and twisting. This isn't always a problem but it can be.

Answer (score 1):

Having been a painter (who coincidentally also did alot of deck staining) I can say that it doesn't really matter.  Stain of course is there to protect and seal the wood but the bottom is not going to get the direct sunlight and moisture the top will.  When fairly easily accessible we always stained the bottom but that was more for aesthetics really because seeing the unstained bottom (especially considering how much stain can run and drip...) looks terrible.

In the end I have never experienced someone being concerned with staining the bottom for sealing reasons, I suppose it wouldn't hurt anything to do it but it is also unnecessary.